# How to asynchronously load and append data to model on checkbox change of component?

Tags: javascript, facebook, asynchronous, ember.js

I am currently developing an ember application which has two components.

One component represents a map the other one represents a friendslist.

Both components are placed in the same handlebar template.

What I try to achieve is that a user can check a checkbox in the friendslist component and in the next step his or her posts are loaded asynchronously from facebook (the friend itself was already loaded in the beforeModel hook). Those asynchronously loaded posts should be append to the already existing friend object in the model. Afterwards the map component should be informed about the changes and refresh itself or call a function which will draw points on the map.

At the moment I am trying to set the checked property of a single friend (which would be the same approach as appending the posts but will be easier for now):

```
// index.hbs
{{map-widget posts=model.posts friends=model.friends}}
{{friends-list checkedFriend='checkedFriend' friends=model.friends}}

// friends-list.hbs (component)
<ul>
  {{#each friends as |friend|}}
    <li>
      {{input type="checkbox" id=friend.facebookID checked=friend.checked change=(action checkedFriend)}}   <p>{{friend.name}}</p>
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>

// friends-list.js (component)
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

  actions: {
    checkedFriend: function () {
      this.sendAction('checkedFriend');
    }
  }
});

// index.js (route)
export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
...
  model: function() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      posts: this.get('currentUserPosts'),
      friends: this.get('friends')
    });
  },

  actions: {
    checkedFriend: function () {
      // Update just the first friend here to see if the approach works
      // Get the friends array from the model
      const model = this.controller.get('model');
      const friends = model.friends;

      // Update the friend
      Ember.set(friends[0], 'checked', true);

      // Map component receives an update here,
      // but "DEPRECATION: You modified (mut model.friends) twice in a single render." warning occurs
      this.set('friends', friends);
    }
  }
})
```

The current approach works more or less. However, I get a depreciation warning that I modified the model twice in a single render which in my opinion is a sign for a bad design from myside.

What I would like know is how a good approach for my task described above would look like. If I am already on the right way I would be glad if anyone could tell me why this double rendering error appears.

***The core problem is how to correctly update the model and how to inform the components especially the component which did not set the action about the changes so that those are refreshed.***

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a Class - FriendEntry. By calling its constructor you will recieve an instance of FriendEntry. Now you will be modifying instance instead of original record (which indeed is not right).

```
var FriendEntry = Ember.Object.extend({
    init: function() {
        this._super(...arguments);
        this.set('somethingFriendly', true);
    }
});

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
      friendsEntries: Ember.computed.map('model.friends', function(friend) {
          // Call the constructor
          return FriendEntry.create({
               friend: friend,
               checked: false,
               posts: []
          })
      })
});
```

Ok so your component would look something like this.

```
{{friends-list checkedFriend='changeFriendCheckedStatus' entries=friendEntries}}


// friends-list.hbs (component)
<ul>
  {{#each entries as |entry|}}

      {{input type="checkbox" checked=entry.friend.checked change=(action checkedFriend entry)}}   <p>{{entry.friend.name}}</p>

  {{/each}}
</ul>

// friends-list.js (component)
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

  actions: {
    checkedFriend: function (entry) {
      this.sendAction('checkedFriend', entry);
    }
  }
});
```

Back to controller

```
actions: {
   changeFriendCheckedStatus(friendEntry) {
         ic.ajax.request(API.HOST + '/someUrlForPosts/' + friendEntry.get('id)).then(givenFriendPosts => {
              entry.get('posts').pushObjects(givenFriendPosts);          
         }) 
   }
}
```

If i understood correctly you have 2 models I friends and posts (DS.belongsTo('friend')). You would need to encapsulate both into friendEntry (friend, posts).

So your map-widget would also look like this `{{map-widget friendEntries=friendEntries}}`

Instead of querying posts in model you could encapsulate them like this.

```
    friendsEntries: function() {    
           return DS.PromiseArray.create({
                  promise: Ember.RSVP.all(this.get('model.friends')).then(friends => {
                    return friends.map(friend => {
                        return FriendEntry.create({
                          friend: friend,
                          checked: false,
                          posts: store.query('posts', { friend: friend.get('id') }
                       });  
                    }); 
                  })
          });
   }.property('model.friends.[]')
```

Comment: but how does the component than be informed that it has to refresh?

Comment: it does just encapsulate my already existing friend object who already has a checked property so I do not exactly understand how this would be better than my existing approach.

Comment: Ok ive added some snippets, however I cant just write this complex code for you outta box without any testing. Hopefully this will work.

Comment: Ok, now its much clearer for me, though I have to say that I am not working with the store in this project, I am working directly with promise response objects from Facebook.

Comment: You dont need to work with store. As i wrote "changeFriendCheckedStatus(friendEntry) " function using ic.ajax. JSON is fine by ember as long as its wraped in ember.object otherwise it will not have auto-update feature in mustache brackets {{thisWillNotUpdate}}

Comment: Ok, fine, what exactly does `this.set('somethingFriendly', true);`? Does it set all friends.checked to true?

Comment: Nah it's just a random piece of code to show entries can share properties. As i construct entry i set "checked" false. For instance if u had multiple calls for "entry.create({ cheked: false})"  you could have that line of code written in the Class "init" method > "this.set('checked', false) . So you wouldnt have to write that line of code more than once.